# Remove tabindex attribute from hyperlink

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, oracle-apex

I have an oracle apex page. I defined a tabscontainer region in it. There are two sub regions to this region. There is a hyper link inside each sub region, which is coded like

```
<a class="t-Tabs-link" href="#SR_R1" role="presentation" tabindex="-1">
  <span>1</span>
</a>
```

in first region and

```
<a class="t-Tabs-link" href="#SR_R2" role="presentation" >
  <span>2</span>
</a>
```

in second region.

I want to remove **tabindex** property of first region from this code using javascript and add property **tabindex="-1"** to second region.I can not add an id to this hyper link since oracle apex do not allow to edit default html attributes. How can I do this without assigning id ? or is there any way that I can assign id to this hyper link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Jquery [removeAttr](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) to remove the attribute from any element.

Select the first index element and simply remove attribute from it

```
$(".t-Tabs-link").eq(0).removeAttr("tabindex");
```

You can also set attribute via Jquery [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function

```
$(".t-Tabs-link").eq(1).attr("tabindex" , -1);
```

**[example](https://jsfiddle.net/bfk6zdgq/)**

Answer (score 6):

You can use `document.querySelector` and you don't need to know `<a>`'s ID.

You can remove `tabindex` by this.

```
document.querySelector('.t-Tabs-link:first-child').removeAttribute('tabindex');
```

You can set `tabindex` by this.

```
document.querySelector('.t-Tabs-link:last-child').setAttribute('tabindex', -1);
```